# Active record has_many through filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

What is the best way to query the experience of an user of a custom type of organization? In other words retrieve only a user experience of a certain type of organizations.

```
User
  has_many :organizations, through: :experience
end

Experience
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :user
end

Organization
  has_many :users, through: :experience
end
```

I am trying to perform something like this:

```
User.first.public_experience
```

This will retrieve all the user experience in organizations of public type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is my solution, i have done a join through the experience model.

```
class User
    has_many :public_experience, -> { public_experience }, :class_name => 'Experience'
end

class Experience
  scope :public_experience, -> { joins(:organization).merge(Organization.publicly_related) }
end

class Organization
  scope :publicly_related, -> { where 'organization_types_id = ?', 1 }
end
```

This allows to have the experience only from the public organizations

Answer (score 2):

You could add another `has_many` association that is restricted to a specific type of organization. For example if your organizations have a boolean variable named 'public', you could then add:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations, through: :experience
  has_many :public_organizations, -> { where public: true}, class_name: "Organization", through: :experience, source: :organization
end

class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :user
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :experience
end
```

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with the syntax of the relation: "syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>"

Comment: I'm very sorry, my mistake. I've now edited my original answer, I hope it'll work now.

Comment: That code works and is very close to my needs, The filtering works fine, but still i want experiences and not organizations back as result.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're storing a boolean 'public' variable in the organizations table, and then want to find all experiences a user has with organizations that have that variable set to true? Or are you saving the boolean in the experiences table?

Comment: The boolean is in the organizations table, attached to organization model not in experience.